# error using mPDF to create more than one PDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I am getting the following error when trying to create a bunch of pdfs...

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /home/my_path/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 19063

If I create one PDF it works great.

My code is like this...

```
$pdfs = array(93333,93037,93335,93336);
foreach ($pdfs as $pdf)
 {
 create_pdf($pdf);
 }
function create_pdf($pdf)
 {
 $file = 'PDF - '.$pdf;
 include('/path_to/mpdf/mpdf.php');
 $mpdf = new mPDF();
 $mpdf->keep_table_proportions = true;
 $mpdf->WriteHTML('testing');
 $mpdf->Output('/path_to/pdfs/'.$file.'.pdf','F');
 }
```

It does still create the first pdf, but not the rest. Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: increase the php script memory with: `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`

Comment: ok, I've set memory limit to -1 and now I get this...

>Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class mPDF in /home/my_path/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 67

Comment: Changed include to include_once, this solved my problem :)

Comment: Or even require_once(...).